# jQuery plugin callback inside function

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

So I am still trying to wrap my head around DIY jQuery plugins, but one of the things im having a hard time figuring out is how to do a callback from within a function inside the plugin. When i do the callback outside of the function it works.

*The examples below have been trimmed down so i dont know if they will work if you try them yourself. Just for example*

**Working example:**

```
$.fn.mvSelect = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
        selectColor: "#cccccc",
        search: true,
        checkbox: true,
        onItemSelected: function () { },
        onItemChecked: function () { }
    }, options);

    this.addClass("ulStyle");
    this.find("li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("itemStyle");

        $(this).click(function (e) {
            $("*").removeClass("itemSelected");
            $(this).addClass("itemSelected");
            settings.onItemSelected.call($(this)); // <-- this one works
        });
    });
};
```

**Non-working example:**

```
$.fn.mvSelect = function (options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        selectColor: "#cccccc",
        search: true,
        checkbox: true,
        onItemSelected: function (e) { },
        onItemChecked: function (e) { }
    }, options);

    function refreshData() {
        that.find("li").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("itemStyle");

            $(this).click(function (e) {
                $("*").removeClass("itemSelected");
                $(this).addClass("itemSelected");
                settings.onItemSelected.call($(this)); // <-- Does not work
            });

        });
        return that;
    };

    if (someThing === "refreshData")
        refreshData();
};
```

I assume this has something to do with the scope as when i look into the scope for that settings item, it shows closure a couple times in the non working version, and in the working version, it doesnt show closure. Either way I cant seem to find any info on how to make it work properly. The events themselves do work, its the callback that isnt making it back to my other code.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you declared "that"? Because you are working with functions (which means different scopes) you need to make sure that "this" is the same "this" every time. a innterfunction does not have access to the outer this. You could use: var that = this; at the function refreshdata. Then use "that" instead of "this" in the following code. I hope you understand what I mean.